# How to implement an OAuth 2 Server

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to create an OAuth 2 Server mainly for self education purposes. I do understand the concepts the OAuth framework is based on and I do understand the the authentication process(what is send/received and why).
I'm pretty familiar with java and the Spring framework as such my intentions are to use this technologies.
My question is, In order to implement an OAuth 2 Server:

1. Do I just follow the [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3) to the letter and write my code based on this? Handling everything by my self? from the data and how its stored in the database(if a database is used) to serving the same error/message response?
2. Do I use a dependency or a library maybe, which will prevent me from reinventing the wheel (as far as OAuth 2 is concerned)?
3. Or is there and already free service which I can install and does exactly with some minor configurations.

Thanks in regards. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're writing something new from scratch, I would recommend you would take a look at the upcoming OAuth 2.1 spec. Largely compatible with OAuth2, but there's a few features removed and some stuff added. It might be worth starting off with something that's immediately the bleeding edge.
2. Yes, probably. Unless you can't find a good one?
3. Yes, there's open source implementations and free hosted services.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, didn't know OAuth 2.1 was a think i will dedicate some time to read the changes. I will live the RFC draft here [OAuth 2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-parecki-oauth-v2-1-03).  Keycloak seems like a nice tool. If i find a nice library i will definitely share.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is **Keycloak**.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll think this is a nice tool l look into it.